# Why does a functions context change when it's instantiated?

Tags: javascript

Why does the context in `foo()` differ when it's invoked through an instantiation?

Also, can `this` ever point to something but the container object (like `window`) in an object scope (the `bar` example below)?

```
function foo(){
    console.log(this === window, this);
}

var bar = {
    getBar: function(){
        console.log(this === bar);
    }
};

foo();
var f = new foo();
bar.getBar();

// Output:
// true
// false
// true
```

http://jsfiddle.net/RUaEA/1/

Comment: Because "this" is funky. It's the function when you instantiate it. Yes, this can be bound late, like in a jQuery iteration or event handler.

Comment: 'this' now has a 'new' context - 'f'

Comment: @DaveNewton Yeah, I know how to manually change the context using `call`/`apply`. I'm just curious why it behaves likes this, and if it's consistent.

Comment: @Johan But that's what you asked, if it can point to something else. "Why" is because that's how JavaScript was written. Yes, it's consistent.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because inside a function, `this` is equal to the global object *unless*:

- you are creating an object with `new`, in which case inside the constructor `this` is bound to the instance being created, or
- the invocation is of the form `obj.func()`, in which case `this` will always be set to `obj`, or
- `this` has been explicitly bound to some value using `call`, `apply` or `bind`

The value of the global object is not specified by the spec, but for JS running inside a browser it is the `window` object.

Comment: I see. And how would I know when "the invocation is of the form `obj.func()`"?

Comment: @Johan he means the dot notation is used to access a property of the object. If the property is a function, and that function is being called, then `this` will be bound to the object on the left hand side of the dot. In this case, it's `obj`.

Comment: @Johan: It depends on the source: `bar.getBar()` is of that form. Note that this means in the general case, `obj.func()` and `var f = obj.func; f()` will result in different `this` values.

Comment: Well, that makes sense for the `bar` object. But I wouldn't say it covers `new foo()`?

Comment: @Johan: That's because you are inside a running constructor, I added another bullet point above